# How to Use AWK within AWK for extracting data with multiple delimeter

Tags: awk

I would like to extract the data from the delimited values having different delimiter.
For example :

file1.txt

```
head|first|java programming|hello|world
```

First level delimeter is |
Second level delimiter is space.

```
awk -F"|" '{print $2," ",$3}'
```

This gives first java programming.

I would like to have printed only

first java

i.e. my second value $3, i have to delimit again.
Note it is space in above example, could also be semi-colon.

i don't want to use pipe as this would be part of bigger awk script block.

Comment: Use the `split()` function, ie `split($2,a,/ /); print $2 " " a[1]`

Answer (score 1):

Use *either* pipe or space as the field separator:

```
awk -F '[ |]' '{print $2, $3}'
```

The default output field separator is space, so `print $2, " ", $3` will print *three* spaces between the words.

Answer (score 0):

If the delimiter can be either a space or a semicolon, you could use a character class `-F"[ ;]"`

Then for each part that you have, you can split on a pipe char, and print the 2nd and 3rd item.

Data

```
$cat file1.txt
head|first|java programming|hello|world
head|first|java;programming|hello|world
```

Example

```
awk -F"[ ;]" '
{
  split($1,a,"|")
  print a[2],a[3]
}
' file1.txt
```

Output

```
first java
first java
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F'|' '{split($3,a,/[ ;]/); print $2, a[1]}' file
first java
```